# Importing .obj with .mtl

Tags: materials, import, file-format

I downloaded a model from the web as `.obj` and `.mtl`. I understand from reading that the `.mtl` should be imported if it is in the same directory and has the same filename. I've verified the filenames match exactly and are both in the same folder. I've edited the `.obj` with a text editor and verified the name of the file in the mtllib line. Is there some other step I'm missing?

Comment: Yes it should be imported. What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: The material names are imported and seem to be assigned to the objects correctly. but no colors nor textures... all white.

Comment: Have you checked that the textures files have the same name as written in the .mtl and that they are also in the same directory?

Comment: Ha ha! I'm new to Blender so you're stretching me. The model didn't come down with any textures and, looking in the .mtl file, I don't see anything that looks like references to external files. Here are the .mtls:

Comment: newmtl None
Ns 0
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.8 0.8 0.8
Ks 0.8 0.8 0.8
d 1
illum 2

newmtl black_plastic
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl card_board
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2

Comment: Well, then that's why it doesn't import textures. If there aren't any texture files and the .mtl doesn't reference them either, then the material simply doesn't have textures.

Comment: Gotcha. But shouldn't it have some color? Those materials come in flat white.

Comment: Yes it should at least have the base color set to the value of `Kd` if I'm not mistaken. This would be (0.64, 0.64, 0.64) a very light gray for both "black_plastic" and "card_board" according to your .mtl. Since I suppose "black_plastic" should be black, the values in your .mtl seem to be wrong.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your helpful responses. I'll know next time where to look for material on model elements I download.